# requestalwaysauthorisation() suddenly disappears

Tags: ios, swift

**CODE A**

```
let locobject = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locobject.delegate = self

    locobject.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locobject.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

**CODE B**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let locobject = CLLocationManager()

    locobject.delegate = self

    locobject.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locobject.startUpdatingLocation() 
}
```

Code A is working fine but when I try to run code B then request dialog suddenly disappears like a flash, why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

In the case of code B, your `CLLocationManager` instance is held in a local variable. As soon as `viewDidLoad` exits it will be released as there is no strong reference to the instance. This causes the dialog to disappear.

In your first code block, the object property holds a strong reference until the object itself is released.

Comment: Kindly elaborate your answer sir

Comment: I suggest you read up on how [ARC](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)  works